# Out of bound exception in imagine library in YII2

Tags: yii2, php-imagine

I am getting following exception while uploading some jpg images(not every image) in my YII2 application

http://grab.by/H09c

It is actually occurring while creating thumb, the full size picture was uploaded well

Comment: you are trying to paste the image data outside the image width / height values. check the values of startx and starty